# Django string concatenation inside template tag best practice

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to concatenate some strings to format a URL inside my template tag, but I don't find an elegant way.

So far, what I have is:

```
{% button "Activate" "http://" site.domain url 'registration_activate' activation_key %}
```

Is there any best practice to make it a bit more "readable"?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 25):

You can concatenate two strings in Django template as follows:

```
{{"First String "|add:"Second String"}}
```

Just replace the two strings with your own variable.

Answer (score 8):

What I use when I want to concatenate strings in Django templates from variables (examples taken from my own code, tell me if you need something closer to your case):

```
<html>
<input id="myid_{{idBase}}_{{idFinal}}" type="checkbox"></input>
</html>
```

and inside a django tag, I use the keyword "add" associated with the keywork with

```
{% with 'images/'|add:file_name as image_static %}
     <img src="{% static image_static %}" title = "{{ tooltip }}"  alt = "{{ title }}"/>
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: This is already more elegant.
What should I do to have |add:url 'registration_activate' activation_key? It expects the "as" keyword and can't resolve the url in this way.
Thanks

Comment: {% url 'registration_activate' activation_key as activation_url %}
I didn't find any more elegant.. Do you think it's best practice?