# django concat string with comma in template

Tags: python, django

I am newbie in django. How can I concat string in a for loop in django template

```
{% for lead in project.leaders %}
    {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
        {% lead_member = lead.0 %}
     {% else %}
        {% lead_member = ','.lead.0 %}
     {% endif %}
{{ lead_member }}
{% endfor %}
```

Finally my `lead_member` should be `test1,test2,test3....`

what is happening now (my current code)

```
 {% for lead in project.leaders %}
    {{ lead.0}}
 {% endfor %}
```

and the output is `test1test2test3....` but i want to make same as `test1,test2,test3....`

Comment: In what language would this make sense? You can't assign in Django templates, but even if you could, repeatedly assigning to the same variable wouldn't create a list. And you don't have any commas anywhere, which was supposed to be the whole point of the question.

Comment: check now my question revised. this is demo code. I want to achieve that what mentioned in last line

Comment: Why do you need to concat at all? the template is just rendering a html page so the output will be the same

Comment: @Sayse again question revised. please check now

Comment: @Sayse your solution will concat extra `comma` if there are only one data. Somewhat confused and couldn't understand what is unclear in my question?? I just want to concat a comma after each data

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this. it works

```
{% for lead in project.leaders %}
    {{ lead.0 }}{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

There's no need to assign anything, nor do you need that type of complexity by using assignment tags. To keep your templating stupid-simple, you could always do this in your view, or even at the model level:

```
# don't step on the `join` built-in
from django.template.defaultfilters import join as join_filter

class Project(models.Model):

    @property
    def leaders(self):
        return join_filter(self.objects.values_list('some_field', flat=True), ', ')
```

Then all you have to do in the template is:

```
{{ project.leaders }}
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried in `views` not worked. However first solution worked.

Comment: I have made a complex data structure (dictionary) using `dict(zip(k,a))`. I can show you if you want

Comment: Sure, send me link to a Gist or something

Comment: https://gist.github.com/rejoan/d35e11adc0886ac3ae51
I need to comma separated `username` for `lm` as well as `nm`. No need to hard work for this as problem is already solved

Comment: Dear Lord. I have no idea what's going on with that Gist :)

Comment: Yeah, what I was saying was that the Gist is very complicated for doing something as simple as concatenating values.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand your question, but I hope i did it. There is a number of related questions such as [String-concatination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27708849/django-string-concatenation-inside-template-tag-best-practice),
[How to concatenate in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386168/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-django-templates)

It's possible to create first string, concatinate it with comma and new string for every iteration. You are also able to make smth like `','.join(list_of_strings)` on your server side before rendering. You can also join your list in templating by `{{ list|join:", " }}`.